# Congratulations Astronomy Stack Exchange for 10k questions!

Tags: discussion, questions, shoutout

I just checked the question count, and discovered that we hit 10k overnight (well actually a few hours after 0:00 UTC) :D

So I just want to say congratulations to everyone here, the moderators, all our contributors at this site, for making Stack Exchange a better place for everybody. CONGRATS FOR 10,000 QUESTIONS!

P.S. Can we get to 15k before [Please comment down below and take a guess]???

Comment: [According to Are 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40709/astronomy), we have a question rate of 6.7 questions per day, which would mean that we hit 15k in about 746 days (~December 2022 or January 2023). However, I think that the question rate is likely to increase.

Comment: Checking the list all sites, we can determine a median of graduation at around 10k questions.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica So when will this site get out of beta?

Comment: @fasterthanlight If the CMs think it so. Their recent decisions have made the impression in me, that they dislike both the Space SE and the Astronomy SE on unknown reasons. The company... well, I believe, they only don't close/sell the SE network because it would be a PR disaster for them. But they want to be the company behind the StackOverflow, and the average company employee has only superficial ideas what could be this stackexchange thing.

Comment: @fasterthanlight For the most part, site graduations have come to a halt network-wide over the past couple of years. I think that's in part due to a lack of resources and personnel on the community management part of things - it's not really an issue specific to Astronomy.

Comment: This is a few weeks late, but Astronomy has graduated! Also we just hit 12k questions, 40 percent to 15 thousand questions after just over a year, @Jonas is almost spot on with the prediction there :)